# DNN Upgrade Module From .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5

I have multiple DNN modules built on .Net 3.5 and DNN 5.2, I upgraded them to DNN 8.1 & .Net 4.6.1, so in the upgraded CMS, some modules are working properly, and others not working (not working without showing any error message or any exception).

To upgrade my modules, I followed these steps:

1. Changed the Target framework of each module project to be 4.6.1.
2. Fix build errors which raised after changing the Target Framework.
3. Build the module project successfully.
4. Copy and replace the file `bin/release/module_name.dll` to `Portal/bin` folder

**Note: for those modules which not working, I can't find any error message describing that I have an issue in the code or something can't be loaded !**

So probably made a mistake or missing some other steps?

**Update:**

After checking the Admin -> Event Viewer, I've found that after dropping the module object inside the page, a General Exception record is inserted to the errors says:

**StackTrace ->** at `DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.ThrowLogError(ModuleInfo module, Exception ex)`

**InnerMessage ->** Value cannot be `null`. Parameter name: `type`

**InnerStackTrace ->**
at `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)`

at `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`

at `DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.GetModuleList(Int32 portalId)`

Comment: This process also creates a web.config file into the project's folder, remove that.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHammond for your timely response, I already deleted web.config file, I think there is a different reason for this issue related to DNN settings

Comment: There should be additional errors as you load. Are there any others in the event Viewer?  Also just confirming that the /bin folder you are speaking of is in the root of the DNN directory structure.

Comment: @MitchelSellers yes the bin folder is in the root of DNN directory.. anyway for my issue, it looks present only on DNN8 because I've found many others having same issue recently on DNNCommunity https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.FormAndList/issues/9

Comment: Ah. Are you using Telerik controls?

Comment: @MitchelSellers yeah true ! .. so you think this issue is because Telerik controls need to be upgraded ?

Comment: Yes it could be @MoamenNaanou there was a change in 8.x that moved the DNN controls that used Telerik into a separate deprecated assembly.

Comment: @MitchelSellers Thanks